# Intellisense - can it get a hint to look at a range of consts?

Tags: c#

If I have a method parameter that is an `enum`, intellisense will pick up the possible values for this enum and let me pick one. This isn't ideal for me however as it's possible people might want to use values outside of my defined set. If I make my argument a `byte` instead, I can then create a static class filled with consts that hold my defined set of values - the only downside is that intellisense does not know about this library of values. Is there a way to point intellisense towards a range of 'helper' values?

Comment: what GUI are you using?

Comment: you can create a new class and require an instance of that class as a parameter for instance.

Comment: The GUI is Visual Studio, so say 2012 or newer.

Comment: Why not make the enum complete? Why allow values that it does not define, that then have no specific meaning in your application?

Comment: The application in question implements a subset of a global standard, which extends to proprietary use. It would be basically impossible to define all possible values - I only need to define helpers for the values that relate to my subset of functionality.

Comment: Then perhaps an enum is not the right solution? Why won't a static class with const values be picked up by autocomplete/intellisense?

Comment: @Kokodoko How would you make intellisense know that in `void DoIt( byte what )` "what" comes from a static class's const values?

Comment: To be more specific, of course the class is picked up by intellisense - but only if you know it is there. Basically I'm looking to see if, at the point of a method being typed and a `byte` being a required parameter, that the IDE suggests that there is a static class that can be used for these possible byte values.

Comment: You can still create a static class filled with constants that hold your values. Just declare these to be the type of the enum: `static class ProprietaryStuff { public const FooEnum WidgetFeature = (FooEnum) 42; }`. However, defining proper, separate enums for this while using base formatter classes that deal with raw `int`s (or `byte`s, as the case may be) seems more appropriate. Just have a `ProprietaryStuff` class with its own `ProprietaryFeatureEnum`. Just because it's "only" for typing doesn't mean it can't be its own thing.

Comment: _"It would be basically impossible to define all possible values"_ - if they fit into `byte` ... ?

Comment: I'm still pondering what you mean by "people might want to use values outside of my defined set". Do you mean other developers who also work on the same project? They could just add their required types to the enum. Or do you mean some end-user who somehow needs to add types at runtime? If you write a class with const values, don't you have the same problem where other users might need const values that you didn't define?

Answer (score 3):

Technically you can assign 'invalid' values to your enum. Since the backing store of an `enum` is an `int`, you can assign any value to it:

```
public enum X
{
    A = 0,
    B = 1
}

class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        X x = (X)2;
    }
}
```

That way, you can still have the IntelliSense support, and allow off-values. Of course, this has drawbacks too, so you have to consider whether they outweigh the pros.

A fix for that could be to assign 'custom' values in your enum, which you reserve for use later on:

```
public enum X
{
    A = 0,
    B = 1,

    Custom1 = 2
}
```

Answer (score 0):

To directly answer the Intellisense part of you question, then no I don't think it is possible to do that.

However I think you can solve your problem by using function overloading, this way you can use either type and have the benefits of both:

```
void Myfunction(MyEnum e)
{
    MyFunction((byte)e);
}

void MyFunction(byte b)
{
    // Do something
}
```